# Passing the user session from express to React state

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, express

I am trying to figure out how I can pass the session id to the React components. So basically after the user login it must redirect to an end point and whatever pages I visit on that site the session id must be available across pages unless destroyed.

I set up an express session:

```
    // setup express session
    app.use(session({
      secret: 'this is your session',
      resave: true,
      saveUninitialized: false
    }));

// make userId available in templates
app.use(function (req, res, next){
  res.locals.currentUser = req.session.userId;
  next();
})
```

And now on my login:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  if( email && password ){
    User.authenticate(email, password, function(err, user){
       if(err || !user){
         return res.status(404).json({error: true});
       } else {
         req.session.userId = user._id;
         res.redirect(303, '/main');
       }
    });
  }
```

The code above will just if the user email and password exist on the database. If it is true then it will set up a session id. Now this session id must be set across pages:

Now on my router for the main page I check if there is an existing session id:

```
router.get('/main', (req, res) => {
  if(! req.session.userId ){
    return res.status(200);
  }

  User.findById(req.session.userId)
      .exec((err, user) => {
        if(err){
          console.log(err)
          res.redirect('/login');
        } else {
          res.redirect('/main');
        }
      })
});
```

If it doesn't exist it must redirect to the same page but if it is it must render the same page.

Now the hardest part for me is how I can make the session id available to the state of my react components globally? I mean I must have a global variable that holds it so I can reference it throughout the front end pages via React?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: req.session.userId,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(`/api/profile/${this.state.id}`)
      .then(response => {
       console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.id}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default UserAgenda;
```

I tried to console.log the req.session.userId and it returns undefined. I need to make it active on my state just like a global variable that is accessible to all the pages until I destroy it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like cookies would work in your use case.

Try adding this to the server code instead of session:

```
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));
```

Then after you authenticate a user set a id cookie (instead of `req.session.userId = user._id`):

```
res.cookie('id', user.id, { signed: true, httpOnly: true });
```

Signed means it will be encrypted client side and httpOnly means it will be passed by the browser automatically (check if you need to set a flag in include credentials in axios)

On the server you can access the cookie (the user id) through `req.signedCookies.id`